# What do you call a person who incessantly thinks only they are good enough to do something?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, pejorative-language

What is the best word or way to describe a person who just has to try and do everything themselves because they think, either rightly or wrongly, that only they are good enough to do the task in hand?

The type of person I'm thinking of will attempt to take over any situation. So if you're having a BBQ only they are good enough to cook the food or if you're planning a day out then they decide only they are good enough to drive you there.

Comment: Control-freak...and other countless pejorative terms besides!

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Friends may half-jokingly call that person the *little dictator/tyrant*.  This is slang but good.

However I think the best word for your details is **imperious**.

> assuming power or authority without justification; arrogant and
>   domineering

Some other words to describe this person would be:

> - **overbearing**... unpleasantly or arrogantly domineering
> - to be "nice" you can say **assertive**... having or showing a confident and forceful personality
> - usually used for a woman (by other women) would be **haughty**... arrogantly superior and disdainful.
> - and the common man's term would be simply **pushy**... excessively or unpleasantly self-assertive or ambitious.

Answer (score 1):

You might call them **perfectionists** since they feel only their efforts are "good enough."

Comment: I might extend it to 'imposing perfectionist' for this particular usage.

Comment: @JonJayObermark Nice improvement.................

Answer (score 1):

Given the level of self-involvement described, I am leaning toward **narcissist**.

I like **egomaniac** for this one too.

**know-it-all** 1.
a person who acts as though he or she knows everything and who dismisses the opinions, comments, or suggestions of others.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [**peremptory**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peremptory).

> **peremptory**: characterized by often imperious or arrogant self-assurance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a narcissist
**Narcissist:** a conceited, self-centered, self-preoccupied person